# NodeJS Sendgrid Issue in sending email to multiple recipients

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am having issue in sending mails to multiple recipients.

My script is

```
var SendGrid = require('sendgrid').SendGrid;
var sendgrid = new SendGrid('<<username>>', '<<password>>');      
    sendgrid.send({
    to: 'nabababa@gmail.com',   
from: 'sengupta.nabarun@gmail.com',
bcc: ["sengupta.nabarun@gmail.com","sengupta_nabarun@rediffmail.com"],
```

I have two questions here

1. Can I have an array of recipients in to list?
2. How can I get an array of recipients in bcc list?

Solutions related to above two queries will be indeed helpful

Thanks
Nabarun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use an array of recipients in both the `to` and `bcc` fields.

For example:

```
var SendGrid = require('sendgrid').SendGrid;
var sendgrid = new SendGrid('{{sendgrid username}}', '{{sendgrid password}}');      
sendgrid.send({
    to: ['one@example.com', 'two@example.com'],
    from: 'nick@sendgrid.com',
    bcc: ['three@example.com', 'four@example.com'],
    subject: 'This is a demonstration of SendGrid sending email to mulitple recipients.',
    html: '<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-P6jNF5dU_UI/TTgpp3K4vSI/AAAAAAAAD2I/V4JC33e6sPM/s1600/happy2.jpg" style="width: 100%" />'
});
```

If this isn't working for you and Node isn't spitting out any errors, check to see if the emails are being sent, by logging into SendGrid's website and looking at the [Email Activity Log](http://sendgrid.com/logs/index).

One thing I came across while testing your code sample is if you're sending the `to` and `bcc` to the same gmail address, gmail will combine it all into one email (so it appears it didn't work). Make sure when testing you're sending email to entirely different accounts.

If you need some email accounts to test with [Guerrilla Mail](https://www.guerrillamail.com/) is an excellent option for creating temporary test accounts.

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution that I ended up with and thought it was more straightforward and could be helpful for folks.

*Note the difference in the shape of the personalizations object.*

### Recipients can see each other:

```js
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

// Declare the content we'll use for the email
const FROM_EMAIL = 'example@example.io' // <-- Replace with your email
const subject = 'Test Email Subject'
const body = '<p>Hello HTML world!</p>'
const recipients = ['alice@example.com', 'bob@example.com'] // <-- Add your email(s) here to test

// Create the personalizations object that will be passed to our message object
let personalizations = [{
    to: [],
    subject
}]

// Iterate over our recipients and add them to the personalizations object
for (let index in recipients) {
    personalizations[0].to[index] = { email: recipients[index] }
}

const msg = {
    personalizations,
    from: FROM_EMAIL,
    html: body,
}

// Log to see what our message object looks like
console.log(msg)

// Send the email, if success log it, else log the error message
sgMail.send(msg)
    .then(() => console.log('Mail sent successfully'))
    .catch(error => console.error(error.toString()))
```

**Personalizations Object**:

```js
{
    personalizations: [{
        to: [
            {email: "alice@example.com"},
            {email: "bob@example.com"},
        ],
        subject: "Test Email Subject"
    }]
}
```

### Recipients can *not* see each other:

```js
// Create the personalizations object that will be passed to our message object
personalizations = []

// Iterate over our recipients and add them to the personalizations object
for (let index in recipients) {
    personalizations[index] = { to: recipients[index], subject}
}
```

**Personalizations Object**:

```js
{ 
    personalizations: [
        {
            to:  "alice@example.com",
            subject: "Test Email Subject"
        }, 
        { 
            to:  "bob@example.com",
            subject: "Test Email Subject"
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a [RunKit](https://runkit.com/taylorjdawson/send-grid-send-1-email-many-recipients) with the full solution and where you can test it out.

Answer (score 2):

The new sendgrid-nodejs update has scrapped previous implementation methods and therefore the accepted answer wont help you now.

So... just an update in case anyone lands to this thread with specific search result.

```
    to: [
      {
        email: 'email1@email.com', 
      },
      {
        email: 'email2@email.com', 
      },
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

For Sendgrid's v3 API, I found their ["kitchen sink" example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/v4.7.1/examples/helpers/mail/example.js#L15) helpful. Here is a relevant bit from it:

```
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail

mail = new helper.Mail()
email = new helper.Email("test@example.com", "Example User")
mail.setFrom(email)

mail.setSubject("Hello World from the SendGrid Node.js Library")

personalization = new helper.Personalization()
email = new helper.Email("test1@example.com", "Example User")
personalization.addTo(email)
email = new helper.Email("test2@example.com", "Example User")
personalization.addTo(email)

// ...

mail.addPersonalization(personalization)
```

Comment: After [reading more about Sendgrid's personalizations](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html), I think you could do multiple to's in a single personalization. That would send one total email, with 2 people in the to field, as opposed to 2 emails to one email each.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for TypeScript (written in ts version 3.4.3 and sendGrid 7.1.1) where you don't want recipients to be able to see each other.

```
import * as sendGrid from '@sendgrid/mail'

type UserEmail = {
  to: string
  subject: string
}
// Add as many recipients as you want
recipients = ['email1@global.com', 'email2@gmail.com']
const personalizations: UserEmail[] = recipients.map(admin => ({
    to: admin,
    subject: 'Inject Subject Here',
}))

try {
    await sendGrid.send({
        from, // Inject
        personalizations,
        html, // Inject
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)    
}
```

`const personalizations` looks like this

```
[{ to: 'email1@global.com',
    subject: 'Inject Subject Here' },
  { to: 'email2@global.com',
    subject: 'Inject Subject Here' }]
```