# Send email to more than one email address

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I want to send email to more than 1 person,my code is in node.js and i m using send grid. When I separate by comma it does not work. and also I want the content of email to be in html format that knows html tags.

these are my codes

```
 let html = "<b>"+"Hi! </br>Someone needs help from a 
 Consultant!</br>" + "Name: " +name + "</br>"+ "Email: " 
 +email+  "</br>"+ "Phone: " +phone +"</br>"+"Organisation: 
"+organisation+"</b>"+ "How can you help: " +howCanWeHelp +"</br>" 
+"Good luck!</b>"
//let html ="hello"

var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
var from_email = new helper.Email(email);
var to_email = new 
helper.Email("x@emain.com,h@email.com,me@email.com");
var subject = "There is a new Consultant Application";
var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', html);
var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);



var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
var request = sg.emptyRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v3/mail/send',
  body: mail.toJSON()
});

sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error response received');
  }
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.headers);
 });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS Sendrgrid Issue in sending email to multiple recepients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455137/nodejs-sendrgrid-issue-in-sending-email-to-multiple-recepients)

Answer (score 1):

For sending emails to multiple users you need to send emails as array of string. So you could add emails using something like:

```
to: [
  {
    email: 'email1@email.com', 
  },
  {
    email: 'email2@email.com', 
  },
],
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212663/5147832) and [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html) for detailed example.

Comment: Yes try doing it